# how to upgrade JDK version from java version "1.8.0_152" to jdk-8u211 in the spring application

Tags: java, spring

I have spring application which has version java version "1.8.0_152" I want upgrade it to java version "1.8.0_211". Same way I have to do Tomcat upgrade as well. please help me

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: My problem is how to upgrade the jdk version for the application

Comment: Are you using Maven project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDK is an Environment whereas Spring Application runs within JDK so you will have to setup the JDK correctly(set JAVA_HOME to point to jdk-8u211) and then run your Spring application within it and not the other way round.

Comment: is there any way that we can set java version in the spring application

Comment: where is option to accep the answer